# Template not showing context variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I created an app called marketing app which customizes messages to be written on top of home page. My problem is that these messages are not showing when everything configured and I don't know why is that might be the template because `{{ marketing_message.message }}` is only not showing

This is the model:

```
class MarketingMessage(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.message[:12])
```

This is the view:

```
from marketing.models import MarketingMessage

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()
        return context
```

This is the template:

```
{% if marketing_message %}
    <div id="top-alert"class="alert alert-light" style="padding-top:85px; margin-bottom:-24px;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <div class="container" style="text-align:center">
        <strong> Marketing Message ! : </strong> {{ marketing_message.message}}
        </div>   
    </div>
{% endif  %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marketing_message` is a QuerySet, not a model instance.

You probably only want the most recent "active" message.

```
context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('timestamp')
```

Or the most recently updated:

```
context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('updated')
```

However `latest()` will fail if there is no object, which is likely not what you want, but you can do this:

```
try:
    context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).latest('updated')
except MarketingMessage.DoesNotExist:
    context['marketing_message'] = None
```

Looking at your data, though, it seems incorrect. You have a start and end dates, but also active. You can imply if something is active if it falls within the start and end dates.

Also, since you have this, it seems like you could have multiple messages at once, in which case you should drop the `.latest()` and iterate over the ones within the start and end dates.

Comment: `context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).sortby('-timestamp')`?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sortby'

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `order_by` ... `context['marketing_message'] = MarketingMessage.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-timestamp')`